# how to open a html file with hidden address bar

Tags: javascript, c#, href, client-side, location-href

I need to open the .html file in which i sent dynamically using C# by calling a javascript function  which is written below

This i have written in C#

```
 Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "", "fncpopup('" + sNewFileName + "');", true);
```

Now i call a function in Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
        //debugger;

        function fncpopup(sFileName)
        {  
            location.href = sFileName;
        }       
    </script>
```

I want to open my .html file in Location.href with URL status bar hidden.How can i do that.

Comment: and what happens?

Comment: It will automatically opens my ,html file in the same window.Idont want to open it in new tab or new window.I want to do it on same page

Comment: Where is `fncpopup` function called? Is a request to server necessary to get response?

Comment: Yes fncpopup  gets called from Server side using page.Page.ClientScript

Answer (score 0):

> I want to open my .html file in Location.href with URL status bar
> hidden.How can i do that.

Use `window.open`

```
    function fncpopup(sFileName)
    {  
        window.open(sFileName, '_blank', 'toolbar=0,location=0,menubar=0');
    }
```

Check more options in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)

Comment: Window.open will show me in a popup I want to do it on the same window.thats why i am using Location.href

Comment: @janakgera then remove `_blank` as the second parameter and keep it empty

Comment: By doing this I am getting my parent page which creates html and Child page which opens the .html with new window.I need to open it in same page.Hence sir I found Window.open is not appt.

Comment: location.href will open the html in the current page. You can't hide the address bar of current page using javascript in a cross browser manner.